# Java言語による電卓開発においてのエラー対応

Tags: java, android

現在Javaで計算機を作っています。全ての計算等の処理は完成し、残りは1÷0などのエラー対応となりました。

そこで、全てのエラーが発生した時にクラッシュせずにTextviewにerrorと表示し、ACボタン以外は受け付けせず、ACボタンで0に戻るようにしたい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問に具体的なコードが一切ないのでイメージですが、以下のような感じになると思います。

```
void ACの処理() {
    // TextView に 0 を表示
    text.setText("0");

    // その他のボタンを押せるようにする
    for (Button btn: otherButtons)
        btn.setEnabled(true);
}

void AC以外の処理() {
    try {
        // 計算処理
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        // TextView に error と表示する
        text.setText("error");

        // その他のボタンを押せないようにする
        for (Button btn: otherButtons)
            btn.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

ボタンは `setEnabled()` で有効化/無効化できます。

ArithmeticException は RuntimeException を継承していますので、計算処理をするメソッドの方に throws を追加する必要はありません。また、計算処理全体を try … catch で囲めば、計算時のエラーをまとめて処理できます。